# List of items with location

Tags: views, 8

try using drupal 8.
I need todo some list of medical help centers.
on 1 page i need to choose "State"->"city"->"zip"->then choose page with medical center in this area.
If i create state,city,zip by taxonomy, how can i logicaly build this state to city to zip to page - linking?
Thank you for advice.

Comment: Why would you build locality information using taxonomy instead of postal address stored on the entity?

Comment: Thank you Kevin for answer. Can you more detail about using entity in my case?

Comment: If you use Address to store location information, then it is easy to build a view and expose those as filters.

Comment: Yes i will use Views to show data. But iam confused about linking Dependencies between "State"->"city"->"zip". What you recommend?